# Why does the C# compiler handle empty async Task methods different to just return Task.CompletedTask?

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization, cil

**Hello,**

**Edit:** the post was edited to not use empty methods to be more clear about what I want to know.

Is there a reason why the C# compile does not compile a `async Task` method without using `await` to return `Task.CompletedTask`?

Sometimes it is necessary to implement a method that returns a `Task` but it is not using `await`.

I am wondering if there is a reason why the generated IL code is so different between that two methods:

```cs
public async Task DoNothing()
{
    Console.WriteLine("nothing");
}
```

```cs
public Task DoNothing()
{
    Console.WriteLine("nothing");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I created two Fiddles where the generated IL code can be viewed.
`async Task`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UQuJUh
`Task.CompletedTask`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eRr4i1

So is there a reason why the compiler does not optimize the code to handle both cases the same way?
Thank you.

Comment: Noone writes empty `async Task` methods, so there's no point. The minute you have code in there (which can throw an exception), the behaviour is different between your two examples: whether the exception is thrown back to the caller of the method, or contained in the `Task`

Comment: That's an extra case they have to handle in the compiler, and you better have a *very* good reason why they should spend time on implementing and testing this, rather than some more important features. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585

Comment: @Sweeper: On the other hand, the compiler does have special code to detect this and generate a warning (not specifically for empty function bodies, but for not using `await` anywhere inside, which is the actual condition under which `Task.CompletedTask` can be used)

Comment: I don´t want to discuss if it is meaningful to write empty methods or not, I want to know if there is a good reason why it is handled differently.
If the reason is no, it´s just not implemented it´s ok, I just want to know if. :D

Thank you @BenVoigt for mentioning that - I change the post to throw away the empty method discussion. :D

Comment: Not an answer but can be useful - [eliding async-await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a significant difference in the way exceptions are handled in those two pieces of code, which are therefore *not equivalent*:

```cs
public async Task DoNothing()
{
    Console.WriteLine("nothing");
}
```

In the case that `Console.WriteLine` raised an exception, the exception is actually internally caught and stored inside the resulting `Task`, indicated by `Task.IsFaulted`. The exception is only actually "thrown" when you use `await` on the task.

```cs
public Task DoNothing()
{
    Console.WriteLine("nothing");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This case however is fully synchronous; the potential exception from `Console.WriteLine` would be raised even before any task could be returned or processed. I'd argue this is actually a bit less safe than the first option, since this behaviour might be unexpected. Iterators show similar behaviour for the difference between `yield break;` and `return Array.Empty<object>();`.

Now your question originally asked about an actually empty method. Well, it could be the case that the method is not actually empty; it may contain breakpoints in debug mode, injected code or perhaps auto-generated checks for the arguments, in the future. Even the empty `try` block is still generated for an empty method body:

```
  .try
  {
    IL_0000:  leave.s    IL_0019
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
  {
```

Now I can imagine an exception in generating `async` method *could* be added to the compiler for the case of a truly empty method, but it would only complicate the code, for no (arguably) real gain. There might be a point of having an empty `async` method (such as to give other programmers who might want to implement it in a future a hint), but then you don't need to care about performance that much to warrant such an optimization (and you have a trivial solution anyway).

(Interesting side note: C# 11 might introduce automatic raising of `ArgumentNullException` from parameters marked with `!!`. At this time, the exception is actually raised *outside* of the `async`/iterator method's code, immediately after the call, so it could be argued that the method body, or what becomes of it, is still, technically, empty.)

Comment: It seems that the parameter null checking (`!!`) feature is unfortunately canceled for C# 11. See "Remove parameter null-checking from C# 11" on https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/